# Link to User Profile Page By Username

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, user-profile

I know this question has been asked a ton of times but I just can't seem to find the answer Im looking for that helps me. So I have created User's profile pages and they work perfectly fine. When I type in the User's Id manually for instance http://localhost:3000/users/3 that specific User's profile page shows up. Now Im looking to be able to link to that current user profile page in my header when that person logs on and looking to be able to link to anyones profile page when they click on the person's username on a post.

This is the error I get from my header when I have the line of code of

```
<%= link_to "Profile", user_path %>
```

[image]

These are my routes

```
resources :posts
devise_for :users
resources :users, :only => [:show]
```

This is my UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user_posts = @user.posts
 end
end
```

And this is my section where I have the username on the posts

```
<div class="panel-body">

    <p><strong><%= @post.user.username if @post.user %></strong></p>
    <p><%= @post.description %></p>
    <% if @post.user == current_user %>
     <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

If you guys need anymore information I will gladly write down more information. And again what Im looking to do is to be able to have a link to the current user profile page in the header when they log on and to be able to click on the username on any post to see that user's profile.

Here are my routes

[image]

Comment: can you show rake:routes

Comment: you want show method work with username instead of ID

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Im sorry Im not to advanced with Ruby

Comment: add this method in model def to_param
    username
  end and try to User.find_by_username in show method controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It expects an id for that route

```
<%= link_to "Profile", user_path(current_user) %>
```

Comment: When I add that I then get a NameError in Posts#index undefined local variable or method `user'

Comment: Editted the answer. Should be using current_user.

Comment: @AwakeningByte he need the routes with username not with id

Comment: Just tried it again and now it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: So the link in the header works perfectly. Thank you for that. Now Im wondering if I click on a post from another user and I want to click on his username and go straight to his page. What would I use for that link

Comment: samething. <%= link_to "Profile", user_path(another_user) %> here another_user is the user you want to view